# Flutter app won't run after flutter SDK upgrade

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

Recently I upgraded the flutter and Dart SDKs and since then I have not been able to run my app locally. I have uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio and the SDKs but I get the same errors.

Here is my flutter doctor -v results:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 2.3.0-13.0.pre.132, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.985], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.3.0-13.0.pre.132 at C:\src\flutter\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision de23eb7b29 (21 hours ago), 2021-05-24 15:34:02 -0400
    • Engine revision b1385c0df1
    • Dart version 2.14.0 (build 2.14.0-145.0.dev)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\nkane\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 4.2.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[√] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\nkane\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.22.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)            • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.212
    • Edge (web)              • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 90.0.818.62

• No issues found!
```

Everytime I try to do anything Android Studio wants to run "flutter pub get" which fails.

```
Running "flutter pub get" in tonnah...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.14.0-145.0.dev.

Because test >=1.16.0-nullsafety <1.16.0-nullsafety.8 requires SDK version >=2.10.0-0 <2.12.0 and test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.8 <1.16.0-nullsafety.18 depends on typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0, test >=1.16.0-nullsafety <1.16.0-nullsafety.18 requires typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0.
And because test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.18 <1.16.0-nullsafety.19 depends on test_api 0.2.19-nullsafety.7, test >=1.16.0-nullsafety <1.16.0-nullsafety.19 requires typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0 or test_api 0.2.19-nullsafety.7.
And because test >=1.15.5 <1.16.0-nullsafety depends on test_api 0.2.18+1 and test >=1.16.0-nullsafety.19 <1.16.6 depends on test_api 0.2.19, test >=1.15.5 <1.16.6 requires typed_data >=1.3.0-nullsafety <1.3.0 or test_api 0.2.18+1 or 0.2.19-nullsafety.7 or 0.2.19.
And because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on both typed_data 1.3.0 and test_api 0.3.0, flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with test >=1.15.5 <1.16.6.
And because test >=1.16.6 depends on yaml ^3.0.0 and flutter_launcher_icons 0.8.1 depends on yaml ^2.1.15, one of flutter_test any from sdk or test >=1.15.5 or flutter_launcher_icons 0.8.1 must be false.
And because no versions of flutter_launcher_icons match >0.8.1 <0.9.0 and tonnah depends on flutter_launcher_icons ^0.8.1, flutter_test from sdk is incompatible with test >=1.15.5.
So, because tonnah depends on both test ^1.15.7 and flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because tonnah depends on both test ^1.15.7 and flutter_test any from sdk, version solving failed.)
```

Not all of these dependencies can be bad now. How do I fix this?

Also, I get this message.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I removed dev_dependencies from the pubspec.yaml file and now I can run the app.